# Problem while rooting : <OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)

Tags: rooting, samsung, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I was trying to root my SM-G920F ,which is running Android 6.0.1, when i received the following message on Odin3.

```
<OSM> Enter CS for MD5..
<OSM> Check MD5.. Do not unplug the cable..
<OSM> Please wait..
<OSM> CF-Auto-Root-zeroflte-zerofltexx-smg920f.tar.md5 is valid.
<OSM> Checking MD5 finished Sucessfully..
<OSM> Leave CS..
<OSM> All threads completed. (succeed 0 / failed 0)
```

the phone was in download mode (Odin) and the developer option is On as it is the case with USB debugging, also the reactivation lock is off.

> Android version : 6.0.1
>   Baseband version : G920FXXU4DPI9
>   Kernel Version : 3.10.61-8821257 Sep 16 2016
>   Build Number MMB29K.G920FXXU4DPIL 
>   KNOX Version : KNOX 2.6

ANY help will be appreciated.

Comment: I now it's very late. Buy maybe you didn't connect your phone before add the necessary files.